# Detect single click events distinguished from click-and-drag or double-click-and-drag

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to distinguish a click event that keeps it distinct from when the user actually ends up dragging the mouse? I have some text that is filled with links, and want it to be easy for the user to click and drag over the text to select some of the text, but the links make this difficult, as the browser interprets it as them trying to drag the link, rather than select some text. So my solution to this problem was to use an `<a onClick=...>` rather than `<a href>`, as the browser lets me drag the mouse over that just like normal text.

However, this only seems to work if I single click and drag the mouse over two separate `<a>` tags: if the selection is entirely internal to an `<a>` tag the event still fires, and if I try to double-click-drag over text it also fires.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to do this other than using `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` and manually keeping track of the delays to determine what the user is doing.

I'm aware that some browsers offer the option to drag through links by holding a modifier key, but I'm curious if there's a simpler way to do this that wouldn't require users to be aware of that functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Opinion piece

Whilst this might be doable, consider accessibility and how it'll fit into your projects needs. Navigation using `onclick` doesn't provide the same accessibility benefits, plus it requires a lot of reinventing things the browser can do for free.

I know that mobile devices typically allow a long press to access a text-select/context menu combo; on desktop, it'll vary per device/browser.

---

##### Actual answer

The only "detect click only" implementation I can think of would be using three  handlers with `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove`. Untested code ahead!

```js
let clicked = false;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', e => { clicked = true; });
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => { clicked = false; });
document.addEventListener('mouseup', e => { 
    if(clicked) {
        // The mouse was clicked without moving it around!
        // Do your "only clicked" logic in here.
    }

    // Reset this back to false for next time
    clicked = false; 
});
```

Comment: @ablygo, don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if it worked for you. :)

Comment: I'd also compare the coordinates of the `mousedown` and `mousemove` events and set `clicked = false` only if they're above a threshold. Otherwise you might get false negatives for clicks that happen without keeping the mouse absolutely steady.

Comment: That seems about what I thought I might have to do if I want this. I was definitely hoping that the browser might have a way to disambiguate. Just testing things now I do see that the browser does navigate through links if you mousedown->mousemove->mouseup, at least in Chrome, provided the amount of movement is below some threshold, so that makes me less big on the idea of trying to reimplement it.

Comment: Also, are there specific accessibility issues that you know this would present, or are you just speaking in terms that there may be? I was hoping that still using an `<a>` tag would be enough for things like screen readers to still understand how to interact with it, but I'm super new to webdev.

Comment: `onclick` isn't always activated by things like keypress events, so people who navigate with keyboards for example, may not be able to actually open the link. There's also the consideration that, when "opening" a link via javascript, it removes the ability of the user to: a) acknowledge what the link does; b) acknowledge where the link will take them; and c) choose how to open said link (in a new tab/window/same page).

Noteably, a screen reader would recognise it as an anchor, however without the `href` attribute, it may not recognise it as a link!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Connor Deckers for idea and for this [site](https://techstacker.com/how-to-detect-double-clicks-with-vanilla-javascript/)

```
let clicked = false;
let dbclicked = false;
let move = false;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', e => { clicked = true; });
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => { move = true; });
document.addEventListener('dblclick', e => { dbclicked = true; });
document.addEventListener('mouseup', e => { 
    if(clicked && !move && !dbclicked) {
        // The mouse was clicked without moving it around!
        // Do your "only clicked" logic in here.
        console.log("clicked without drag and not a double click ");
    }
    if(dbclicked) {
      // The mouse was double clicked
      // Do your "double clicked" logic in here.
      //console.log("dbclicked");
    }


    // Reset this back to false for next time
    clicked = false; 
    move = false;
    dbclicked = false;
});
```

Comment: Just trying out on this page https://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse.html makes me think I would probably need to do the mouseup code asynchronously after a small delay to handle double clicks, as it looks like the events don't happen in the order I would need to disambiguate.